# How to pass id into foreach-loop to fetch all relevant records?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, codeigniter

I want to pass where condition in my model method, So I want to pass all the emp_id i get in an array to a for each loop and want that in my model method so i can pass it as where condition.

The Scenario is: I have a table users which contains all the user identified my unique id called **emp_id** now I have a table called daily_data2 which has login and logouts of users with emp_id there as well. So  i have mapped the emp_id of users with emp_id of daily_data2

This is my controller method:

```
 public function index()
 {
     $user_type = $this->session->userdata('user_type');
     if($user_type=="admin")
     {
      $users = $this->data['users'] = $this->user_m->get();
      foreach ($users as $user) 
      {
        $user->emp_id;
        $this->data['attendances'] = $this->attendance_m->all_login($user->$emp_id);
        $this->data['attendances_logouts'] = $this->attendance_m->all_logout($user->$emp_id);        
      }
        $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/dashboard/index';
        $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main',$this->data);

     }
```

and in my model methods i have two methods one fetches login array and another the logout array which i pass to view and there i calculate the total working hours of a users.

So now i want to pass the emp_id in my model method to get each users' login and logout dynamically.

this is model:

```
 public function all_login($emp_id)
{

      $this->db->where->('emp_id',$emp_id);
}
```

Comment: Reduce your code and point out where you get actual problem?

Comment: i want to pass and id in model dynamically How to do that? the $users array contains all the users

Comment: I want to pass those users array's emp_id to model so what i can use the emp_id in where condition

Comment: format it proper and tell where is the problem and what is the problem?

Comment: @Rajan aren't you getting `$emp_id` in model?

Comment: @PathikVejani  i just want to pass emp_id from users array to my model attendance_m so that i can use the emp_id in where condition there

Comment: @PathikVejani in model it says emp_id is ambigous

Comment: @Rajan post your whole code of function `function all_login($emp_id){}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/100231/discussion-between-rajan-and-pathik-vejani).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify your functions (keep your backup):

```
<?php
public function index()
{
    $user_type = $this->session->userdata('user_type');
    if($user_type=="admin")
    {
        $users = $this->user_m->get();
        $all_empids = implode(',', $users['emp_id']);
        $data['all_empids'] = $all_empids;
        $this->data['subview'] = 'admin/dashboard/index';
        $this->load->view('admin/_layout_main',$this->data);
    }
}

public function get_login_or_logout($eid)
{
    $q = $this->db->query("SELECT entry FROM daily_data2 WHERE emp_id = $eid");
    if($q->num_rows() > 0) {
        $d = $q->row_array();
        $temp = $d['entry'];
        if($temp > 100) {
            return 'login';
        } else {
            return 'logout';
        }
    } else {
        return 'No data found';
    }
}

?>
```

**In View:**

```
<?php
$explode_empids = explode(',', $all_empids);
foreach ($explode_empids as $eid) {
    $check_login_or_logout = $this->user_m->get_login_or_logout($eid);
    echo $check_login_or_logout;
}
?>
```